# User interface of desktop application using SWT

Tags: user-interface, swt

I'm working on a desktop application using SWT. I need to make the UI look and feel like Skype's interface. Can anybody suggest me something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [presentations package](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/presentations/package-summary.html) allows the customization of the look of a SWT application.

Here's a general presentation, including a lot of links : http://jroller.com/mpermar/date/20050619#eclipse_presentations_jlibrary_and_vs

Of course you'll have a lot of work if you don't find an existing skin suitable to your need.